# Mensagem Instant Run no AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

Atualizei AndroidStudio para 2.2.2 e o SDK para API 25, no build.gladle coloque targetSdkVersion 25.

Quando pedi para executar o aplicativo (dispositivo físico) apareceu a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que precisa ser instalado?
Será instalado na IDE ou no dispositivo?

Comment: Clique install and continue e instala todo SDK necessário para que seu AndroidStudio funciona. Sugiro que veja o link :
https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mensagem indica que não tem instalada a versão da API do emulador/dispositivo escolhido para executar a aplicação.

No seu caso escolheu um emulador/dispositivo com o Android 5.1(Lollipop), para que o InstantRun o possa instalar é necessário que você instale ou tenha instalada, no seu computador, a API correspondente a essa versão, neste caso a *API Level* 22.

Se escolher a opção <kbd>Install e continue</kbd> a instalação é feita automáticamente.